# how to take values from user 2nd time on tkinter entry widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Here I am writing a code to give a different "mode" option to the user, after pressing the mode button my entry widget pops up and takes two values from the user for further work.
once the user presses the "enter" button my widget will be destroyed.
Here is my code ,it successfully takes values once from the user but when the user gives values 2nd time it shows error.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
root.title("User Interface Monitor")
rpm=tk.StringVar()
tim=tk.StringVar()
def  enter():
    global rpm,tim
    root.rpmLabel=tk.Label(root,text="enter rpm value:")
    root.rpmLabel.grid(row=0)
    root.timeLabel=tk.Label(root,text="enter time in sec")
    root.timeLabel.grid(row=1)
    root.e1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=rpm)
    root.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    root.e1.delete(0,"end")
    root.e2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=tim)
    root.e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
    root.e2.delete(0, "end")
    #rpm=rpm.get()
    #tim=tim.get()
    #return rpm,tim
def gett():
    global rpm, tim
    rpm = rpm.get()
    tim = tim.get()
    print(rpm)
    print(tim)
    root.rpmLabel.destroy()
    root.e1.destroy()
    root.timeLabel.destroy()
    root.e2.destroy()
    #e1.pack()
    #e2.pack()
root.Button1=tk.Button(root,text="MODE1",command=enter)
root.Button1.pack()
root.Button1.place(x=200,y=200)
root.Button2=tk.Button(root,text="Enter",command=gett)#root.Button2.pack()
root.Button2.place(x=260,y=200)
root.mainloop()
```

Here is my error

```
C:/Users/RAM/PycharmProjects/timing/rpm.py
23
2
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RAM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/RAM/PycharmProjects/timing/rpm.py", line 25, in gett
    rpm = rpm.get()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am new to Python, I couldn't find the solution for this error as tried with "delete" and "reset".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `rpm` starts out as a `StringVar` and then you reset it to be a string in this line of code:

```
rpm = rpm.get()
```

Once that line of code runs, `rpm` is no longer a `StringVar`. A simple solution is to use a different name when fetching the value:

```
rpm_value = rpm.get()
```

Answer (score -1):

Here, after carefully observing the error messages...
I changed my code line as Bryan suggested

```
rpm = rpm.get()
tim = tim.get()
```

to

```
rpm_value = rpm.get()
tim_value = tim.get()
```

then it works exactly as I want.
here is my output:

```
C:/Users/RAM/PycharmProjects/timing/rpm.py

rpm is : 740
time is : 12
want to test again?
enter values again
rpm is : 920
time is : 18
want to test again?
enter values again

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I don't get why this got down voted.The code is perfectly working